Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `lgrenc.def' not found
I am using LyX 2.4.1 installed in Fedora 40 and getting Package fontenc Error: Encoding file 'lgrenc.def' not found. Following the answers here I tried installing all the packaged named there, i.g. texlive-lang-greek, cbfonts, etc. but dnf cannot find any.

google suggests this is the fedora package https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/texlive/texlive-greek-fontenc/

I solved this with sudo dnf install texlive-greek-fontenc-11:svn66612-71.fc40.noarch.
